# Mac office 2011 keep asking me to save doc that I didn't make change

Tags: ms-office

Sometime I just open a doc for viewing, Mac office 2011 keep asking me to save doc that I didn't make change. I've been experiencing this gimmick for the last 12 months. And it got to stop since it was so annoying.

My office build id 14.0.0 (100825) FYR

Comment: Every version of Office I've used, on any platform, since the dawn of time has done this. Opening the doc updates metadata properties in the doc that require your permission to save permanently to disk.

Comment: but it doesn't always require to save. Sometimes it does sometimes not. so how can we explain that?

Comment: It always does for me.

Answer (score 2):

This is in fact not supposed to happen if you haven't changed a thing in the  document. I have experienced this myself some time ago, if I remember correctly.

To troubleshoot this, I recommend deleting the Word preference file and, of course, to install the current Office 2011 update. 14.0.0 is the 'virgin' first release. Those are usually laden with bugs, quirks, and vulnerabilities which only get corrected with subsequent updates – the current update version is 14.2.3!

1. Quit all Office applications.
2. In the Finder, go to the top menu bar and choose `Go > Go to Folder` (or press Cmd-Shift-G.) Then type or copy-paste following exact folder path into the input field:

   ~/Library/Preferences
3. Drag the files `com.microsoft.Word.plist` and `com.microsoft.Word.plist.lockfile` into the trash. Then launch Word again to check if the problem is gone.

To update Office: Open Word, go into the Help menu and chose 'Check for Updates'. You can also download update packages and install them manually –  download from http://www.microsoft.com/mac/download